# Remove a specific element from an array-like string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to remove only element `1` from the string `'[1,11, 1, 111,12,1,11]'` in Postgres, without affecting the other elements. Symbols `11` and `111`, `12` should not be affected.

The end result should be the string `'[11,111,12,11]'`

I tried different replace options `REPLACE(%s,' 1,','')`, `REPLACE(%s,'1 ,','')`.

Comment: Actually you need to remove element 1 from the array, right?

Comment: Given that sample string what **exactly** is the result you want. Show the actual result in addition to your description. Please add this as an update to the question not as a comment.

Comment: yes! remove element 1

Answer (score 0):

Inside out: first replace `[` and `]` with `{` and `}` for correct array syntax, then cast the resulting string to a text array and `unnest` it into a table of strings. Select elements that are not equal to '1', aggregate the resultset back into a string and format it within square brackets.

```
select format('[%s]', string_agg(e, ','))
from unnest(replace(replace('[1,11, 1, 111,12,1,11]','[','{'),']','}')::text[]) e
where not e = '1';
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qou7bMJqV5VewdK9XEpbgY/2)

Answer (score 0):

That string is a valid `jsonb` array literal, so you can use [`jsonpath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.20.1.1.1), then cast it back to `text`. It adds uniform spacing after each comma on its way back. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/3u8KvYSJ)

```sql
select jsonb_path_query_array('[1,11, 1, 111,12,1,11]'::jsonb,'$?(@<>1)')::text;
```

You can also make it into a regular array literal, use [`array_remove()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.11.1.1.1), then cast back, which removes spaces after comma separators:

```sql
select translate(array_remove(translate('[1,11, 1, 111,12,1,11]','[]','{}')::int[]
                              ,1)::text,'{}','[]');
```

There of course is a way to do it purely in `text`:

```sql
select replace(regexp_replace(replace('[1,11, 1, 111,12,1,11]',    ',' ,']['),
                                      '\[[^\w]*1[^\w]*\]','',1,0), '][',',' )
```

Which maintains original spacing, without adding or removing anything that didn't belong to the removed element's slot, if it's important. For example `' 111'` will keep its leading space. The use of [`\w` word character class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS) makes it also work with elements that aren't only made up of digits.